# Is "since" necessary in the sentence? "Never speak harsh words, since once spoken they may return to you."

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions, writing-advice

I got this sentence from my English class. Some said 'since' can be omitted.

Comment: You'd have to replace the comma with a dash say, but the 'since' can quite readily be inferred. << “Never speak harsh words. Once spoken they may return to you.” Yes, it's punchier without the 'since'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Since* in this sentence is a [conjunction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjunction); both parts of your sentence are complete sentences by themselves, so you need a conjunction word (or a semicolon) to join them together.  Without *since*, this becomes a [run-on sentence](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/run-on-sentence-basics/).